# Sending an email from python using unique values from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, email

I am trying to send an email from Python based on unique values from a pandas dataframe. I am able to trigger an email to a single user. When i try to send it to by validating if the user or team exists it does not work.

```
import smtplib
import email
import email.mime.multipart 
import email.mime.text
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

contacts = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Contacts\Contacts.xlsx',
                 sheet_name = 'EMAIL',
                 header = 0
                 )
releases_data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Hourly Releases\Releases.xlsx'
                    ,header = 0)
team_data=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Hourly Releases\EE Details.xlsx
                       , header = 0)
team_data_applied=pd.merge(left=team_data,right=releases_data,on = 'Empl ID')
unique=team_data_applied['Team'].unique()

for team in unique:
    manager = team_data_applied[team_data_applied['Team']==team]
    subject = "#MS#"+Team+"- Hourly Releases"

    body = """
Hi, 
Below is the snap shot of team's hourly releases.
"""
mail_body = body + "\n"+str(manager)

MY_ADDRESS="xyz@abc.com"
PASSWORD = '******'
toaddr = "teammanager1@abc.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = MY_ADDRESS
msg['To'] = toaddr

msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smpt-outlook.mail.com',port=25)
server.starttls()
server.login(MY_ADDRESS,PASSWORD)
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS,toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Using this code i am able to trigger the email to single user. I tried to create two functions and then call them in a main function to send the email. The code worked. Without any email being triggered.

Below is the functions that i created.

```
def team_content():
    for team in unique:
        manager =team_data_applied[team_data_applied['Team']==team]
        subject = "#MS#"+Team+"- Hourly Releases"

        body = """
    Hi, 
    Below is the snap shot of team's hourly releases.
    """
    mail_body = body + "\n"+str(manager)

        print(mail_body)
    return team,manager,mail_body,subject



def get_contacts():
    contacts = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Contacts\Contacts.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'EMAIL',
                     header = 0
                     )
    for index , row in contacts.iterrows():
         teams = contacts['TEAM']
         emails = contacts['EMAIL']

    return teams, emails 

def main():
    team,manager,mail_body,subject =team_content()
    teams, emails = get_contacts()

    server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp-outlook.mail.com',port=25)

    for team,manager,mail_body,subject in zip(team,manager,mail_body,subject):
        for teams, emails in zip(teams, emails):
            if team == teams:
                msg.attach(MIMEText(mailbody, 'plain'))
                msg['From'] = xyz@abc.com
                msg['To'] = emails
                msg['Subject'] = subject

                text = msg.as_string()
                server.sendmail('xyz@abc.com',emails, text)

                server.quit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Not sure what to change so that i could trigger the email. Works fine if i use a single email.